# stuck with this while loop java

Tags: java

I have been working with while loops however I cant seem to understand how the remainder works inside this code.

```
int a = 10;
while( a <= 1000 && a % 100 != 0){
System.out.println("a = " + a);
a = a + 10;
}
```

Comment: doubt that compiles.

Comment: is it just me who doesn't understand what the OP means by *remainder* here?

Comment: Could it be that you mixed up bitwise and operator `&` and remainder operator `%`?

Comment: @MichaelButscher that explains it. The code works after replacing `&` with `%`.

Comment: sorry, there is a type in a & 100 != 0 the & should be %

Comment: pls update your code and make details about your issue and your aim. Your question makes readers confused.

Answer (score 1):

```
a & 100 != 0
```

Performs bitwise and , then compares the result to 0. It will be false even in the first iteration, since 10 & 100 = 0

Comment: `a & 100 != 0 ` is not `(a & 100) != 0` as you seem to suggest, instead it's `a & (100 != 0)` which renders a compilation error. anyhow it seems like a typo and the OP meant `a % 100 != 0`.

Comment: sorry did not noticed the typo the & in  a & 100 != 0 should be %